# jQuery mobile panels

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am trying to add a panel to use as a side menu, but it looks like I am doing something wrong. I've tried troubleshooting it but can't see where the issue is.

The panel is not hidden by default (not sure if that's how it should behave) and I can't get it slide out/in.

Here's what I have. I appreciate your help.

```
<!-- @ Page = menu -->
<div data-role="page" id="menu">

    <div data-role="panel" id="myPanel" class="main_nav" data-display="push"  data-dismissible="true" data-theme="a">

        <div class="nav_profile">
            <div class="nav_thumb"><img src="images/nav_thumb.png" width="64" /></div>
            <div class="nav_name">
                <h3>user</h3>
                <p>2 active threads</p>
            </div><!--/nav_name-->
        </div><!--/nav_profile-->


    </div><!-- /panel -->

    <div data-role="header" class="header" data-position="fixed" role="banner" >

        <h3>Threads (2)</h3>
        <a href="#" class="right menu_button">New</a>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <a href="#myPanel" data-rel="panel" data-role="button" class="menu_icon left" ></a>
        <div class="head_search">
            <input type="text" class="search rounded" placeholder="Search" />
        </div>


    </div>

</div><!--/menu-->
```

Comment: I don't see any JQuery to control the panel. It's loading with defaults. Could you add your JQuery code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/panels/index.html

> A panel's visibility is toggled by a link somewhere on the page or by
>   calling the panel's open method directly. The defaults place the panel
>   on the left and it will be revealed. Open a panel programmatically
>   like this:
>
> `$( "#idofpanel" ).panel( "open" , optionsHash );`
>
> To control a panel from a link, point the href to references the ID of
>   the panel you want to toggle (mypanel in the example above). This
>   instructs the framework to bind the link to the panel. This link will
>   toggle the visibility of the panel so tapping it will open the panel,
>   and tapping it again will close it.
>
> `<a href="#mypanel">Open panel</a>`

I put your code in a jsFiddle and found no problems, the panel opens properly: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/Ej7A7/1/

Make sure you're using the latest JQuery and JQM Frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but in my case the CSS file (download from the jQuery mobile site) seemed to be corrupted. After downloading the theme-free CSS file it worked as expected. The issue seems to be fixed now though!